# Error of writing excel with a number of data by Using oledb

Tags: c#

I get a problem with inserting data into Excel using oledb

The problem: when I try to write less than 65000 lines of data into Excel, it works. But when I try to write more than 65000 lines, an error occurs:

> Spreadsheet is full

I guess there is a limit to write date at one time...

I have more than 1,000,000 lines of data to write...

A line consists of 6 columns and appoximately 100 characters

Here is my source code.

```
private static OleDbConnection CreateConnection(string ExcelPath)
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        ConnectionBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
        ConnectionBuilder.DataSource = ExcelPath;
        ConnectionBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0");
        return new OleDbConnection(ConnectionBuilder.ToString());
    }

using (OleDbConnection Connection = CreateConnection(@"C:\userinfo.xls"))
        {
            Connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand tempCmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
            tempCmd.CommandText = CreateTableQury(dt, "Sheet1");
            tempCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tempCmd.CommandText = CreateInsertQuery(dt, tempCmd.Parameters, "Sheet1");
            int extime = 1;
            foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < tempCmd.Parameters.Count; t++)
                {
                    tempCmd.Parameters[t].Value = Row[t];

                }
                tempCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                extime++;
                if ((extime % 1000) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("EXCEL " + extime + " Line / time:" + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                }
            }
            Connection.Close();
        }


public static string CreateTableQury(DataTable Table, string SheetName)
    {
        string Query = "CREATE TABLE [" + SheetName + "] (";

        for (int i = 0; i < Table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Query += Table.Columns[i].ColumnName + " text";
            if (i < Table.Columns.Count - 1) Query += ", ";
            else Query += ")";
        }

        return Query;
    }

    public static string CreateInsertQuery(DataTable Table, OleDbParameterCollection Parameters, string SheetName)
    {

        string Query = @"INSERT INTO [" + SheetName + "] VALUES (";

        for (int i = 0; i < Table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            Query += "@Param" + i.ToString();

            if (i < Table.Columns.Count - 1) Query += ", ";
            else Query += ")";

            OleDbParameter Parameter = new OleDbParameter("@Param" + i.ToString(), DbType.String);
            Parameters.Add(Parameter);

        }

        return Query;
    }
```

Comment: Guess you will have to upgrade Excel to atleast 2007 version Or expand across columns

Comment: Well then it seems the file is not for 2007, userinfo.`**xls**`

Comment: Also i think you would need to upgrade `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB` also

Comment: hm.. I have MS Office 2007.. I guess it doesn't matter wether I have MS offic excel program or not (if I use Micocoft.Office.Interop.Excel, it matter i think)

Comment: I didn't get your point ? The format xls you are using is for older versions of Excel which have the 65K limit

Comment: Thank you so much.. I get your point so I tried to change my code ConnectionBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0"); --> ConnectionBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0"); it says " Can't fine installable ISAM" even MS OFFICE 2007 is installed my PC..

Comment: Thank you for your help I solve it! I changed my Connecting code like ConnectionBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";ConnectionBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"); It works!! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

It might the version you opened in 2003. Because when you open 2003 excel in 2007, it won't have more than 65K rows.

Hence, Please save the excel into 2007 and try the same.